# How to fix ‘InvalidArgumentException : indexSize must be at most 5’ error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to fill the table blog_posts using the faker, but I get this error.

```
InvalidArgumentException  : indexSize must be at most 5
```

BlogPostFactory.php

```
    <?php

    /* @var $factory \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory */

    use App\Models\BlogPost;
    use Faker\Generator as Faker;

    $factory->define(BlogPost::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $title = $faker->sentence(rand(3, 8), true);
    $text = $faker->realText(1000, 8000);
    $isPublished = rand(1, 5) > 1;

    $created_At = $faker->dataTimeBetween('-2 months', '-3 months');

    $data = [
        'category_id' => rand(1, 11),
        'user_id' => (rand(1, 5) == 5 ) ? 1 : 2,
        'title' => $title,
        'slug' => Str::slug($title),
        'excerpt' => $faker->text(rand(40,100)),
        'content_raw' => $text,
        'content_html' => $text,
        'is_published' => $isPublished,
        'published_at' => $isPublished ? $faker->dataTimeBetween('-2 months', 
           '-1 days'): null,
        'created_at' => $created_At,
        'updated_at' => $created_At
    ];


    return $data;
    });
```

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
    <?php

    use App\Models\BlogPost;
    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

    class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
    {

        public function run()
        {
            $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(BlogCategoriesTableSeeder::class);
            factory(BlogPost::class, 100)->create();
        }
    }
```

I use Laravel 5.8

Comment: Is there any more information on the error - like a stack trace to show what part of the code needs the index?

Comment: InvalidArgumentException  : indexSize must be at most 5

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\Urok\vendor\fzaninotto\faker\src\Faker\Provider\Text.php:40
    36|             throw new \InvalidArgumentException('indexSize must be at least 1');
    37|         }
    38| 
    39|         if ($indexSize > 5) {
  > 40|             throw new \InvalidArgumentException('indexSize must be at most 5');
    41|         }
    42| 
    43|         $words = $this->getConsecutiveWords($indexSize);
    44|      $result = array();

Comment: it is all error messege

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error stack trace, it is pointing to a line in the Faker code for `realText`:

```
public function realText($maxNbChars = 200, $indexSize = 2)
{
    if ($indexSize > 5) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('indexSize must be at most 5');
    }
}
```

Thus, Faker only allows an index size of 5 at most.  So, to fix your issue, change your code from:

```
$text = $faker->realText(1000, 8000);
```

To something less than 5 on the second parameter:

```
$text = $faker->realText(100, 4);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Now this Error has appeared

Comment: InvalidArgumentException  : Unknown formatter "dataTimeBetween"

Comment: That's a totally different issue.  Review Faker documentation to see how the `dataTimeBetween` works, but the above should solve the index error for your question.  Looks like a **TYPO** - Should it be date maybe??